# 301 redirect is working for www.example.com but not for 

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I am getting a strange problem with 301 redirect it the code is working for with www in the link and not working for with out www

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^api$ http://example.com/topic/api [R=301,L]
```

if i type http://www.example.com/api it works but if i do http://example.com/api it doesnt work

Adv thanks
prasanth

Comment: it si giving me 404 error of not able to find page at http://www.example.com/api.

Comment: Maybe your virtual host is only configured for `www.example.com` and not `example.com`.

Comment: Are you have line? RewriteEngine on

Answer (score 0):

Check your Virtual Host configuration should be like below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

If the page is not found, it is possible that the example.com and www.example.com point to difference directory, otherwise, example.com may not linked to any place yet.